# How to get the nested struct from variable from a string representation?

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON file looks like following somehow

```
{
    "type": "Weekly",
    "clients": [
        "gozo",
        "dva"
    ],
    "sender": "no-reply@flowace.in",
    "recipients": {
        "gozo": [
            "a@gmail.com",
            "b@hotmail.com"
        ],
        "dva": [
            "c@gmail.com",
            "d@hotmail.com"
        ]
    },
    "features": [
        "Top5UsedApps",
        "TimeSpentOnEachL3",
        "NewlyAssignedL3",
        "HoursLogged"
    ],
    "dbCloning": [
        "dva"
    ] 
}
```

I have mapped structs like the following.

```
type receivers struct {
    Gozo []string `json:"gozo"`
    Dva  []string `json:"dva"`
    // Add more recievers
}

// Config -- The config object parsed from the JSON file
type Config struct {
    ReportType string    `json:"type"`
    Clients    []string  `json:"clients"`
    Sender     string    `json:"sender"`
    Recipients receivers `json:"recipients"`
    Cloning    []string  `json:"dbCloning"`
}
```

Then somewhere in the another source file, I do the following,

```
func main() {
    conf := LoadConfig(os.Args[1])
    for _, client := range conf.Clients {

        // Use the client variable of some other function calls

        fmt.Println(conf.Recipients[client]) // This will not work
}
```

Now my question is how can I make it work. I can not loop over `conf.Recipients` directly.

PS: Consider that `LoadConfig` function unmarshal the JSON and returns a `conf` object.

**Edit 1:** It looks like it was design decision error. Now going with the solution of `map[string][]string`. But not marking it as an answer because the need to know how it is easily done for all the cases where there was no other choices.

Comment: You can't access your `receivers` structure using the `[]` operator.

Comment: Yeah I know..But how can I do it in other way..the idea is that the client needs to be dynamic

Comment: Because receivers is not a slice it is a struct.

Comment: If it should be dynamic, a map would be great, you don't want to define a type for that if you want it to be able to have new clients added without changing your code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your type `receivers` shouldn't have named fields. It should be a `map[string][]string` instead.

Here is a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Config struct {
    ReportType string              `json:"type"`
    Clients    []string            `json:"clients"`
    Sender     string              `json:"sender"`
    Recipients map[string][]string `json:"recipients"`
    Cloning    []string            `json:"dbCloning"`
}

var data = []byte(`{
    "type": "Weekly",
    "clients": [
        "gozo",
        "dva"
    ],
    "sender": "no-reply@flowace.in",
    "recipients": {
        "gozo": [
            "a@gmail.com",
            "b@hotmail.com"
        ],
        "dva": [
            "c@gmail.com",
            "d@hotmail.com"
        ]
    },
    "features": [
        "Top5UsedApps",
        "TimeSpentOnEachL3",
        "NewlyAssignedL3",
        "HoursLogged"
    ],
    "dbCloning": [
        "dva"
    ] 
}`)

func main() {
    var conf Config
    json.Unmarshal(data, &conf)

    for _, client := range conf.Clients {
        fmt.Println(conf.Recipients[client])
    }
}
```

Gives the output

```
[a@gmail.com b@hotmail.com]
[c@gmail.com d@hotmail.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

A range clause provides a way to iterate over an array, slice, string, map, or channel. So you cannot range over struct until you convert it into one of the above types.

To loop over struct fields you can go for reflection by creating a slice of reflect value for struct.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type receivers struct {
    Gozo []string `json:"gozo"`
    Dva  []string `json:"dva"`
    // Add more recievers
}

// Config -- The config object parsed from the JSON file
type Config struct {
    ReportType string    `json:"type"`
    Clients    []string  `json:"clients"`
    Sender     string    `json:"sender"`
    Recipients receivers `json:"recipients"`
    Cloning    []string  `json:"dbCloning"`
}

var data = []byte(`{
    "type": "Weekly",
    "clients": [
        "gozo",
        "dva"
    ],
    "sender": "no-reply@flowace.in",
    "recipients": {
        "gozo": [
            "a@gmail.com",
            "b@hotmail.com"
        ],
        "dva": [
            "c@gmail.com",
            "d@hotmail.com"
        ]
    },
    "features": [
        "Top5UsedApps",
        "TimeSpentOnEachL3",
        "NewlyAssignedL3",
        "HoursLogged"
    ],
    "dbCloning": [
        "dva"
    ] 
}`)

func main() {
    var conf Config
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &conf); err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(conf.Recipients)

    values := make([]interface{}, v.NumField())

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        values[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }

    fmt.Println(values)
}
```

Working Code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ht3vDwUkgse)

> `NumField` returns the number of fields in the struct v. It panics if
>   v's Kind is not Struct.

```
func (v Value) NumField() int
```

> `Field` returns the i'th field of the struct
>   v. It panics if v's Kind is not Struct or i is out of range.

```
func (v Value) Field(i int) Value
```

Interface returns v's current value as an interface{}.

```
func (v Value) Interface() (i interface{})
```